# How to create full width image splash screen for react native ios app in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, uiview, uiimageview

My application require a splash screen with a round logo in the middle , the background has some design overlays, So I need the splash screen as a full screen image. I have referred to several post but could not find out how to create the splash screen to fit different screen resolution.

I have created 3 images as Default.png (414 x 736) Default@2x.png (1080 x 1920) and Default@3x.png (2048 x 2732) And I have used LaunchScreen.xib for implementing my splash screen with an outer UIView and an inner UIImageView with an intention for holding the Default.png image as full screen. In emulator, some of the devices shows blank spaces  horizontally and in tab vertically.

I think I need to add more images for different resolutions. Can somebody help me to get rid of this issue of adding full screen splash image

Comment: Do you mean you want to use a splash image that fills the screen?

Comment: Yes, I can create full screen images for different screen sizes (this is necessary as the image is full screen and it has a logo in center and some gradients, so it should not cut off with differnt screen sizes) , but what is the naming conventions for the image name and how to load if based on devices

Comment: any answer for this issue?

Comment: @hongdeveloper https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59169791/how-to-create-launchscreen-with-a-fullscreen-image-for-ios-in-react-native-which  This link seems like an optimal solution