# How to create LaunchScreen with a fullscreen Image for IOS in React Native which is screen compatible with iPad and all iPhones

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ipad, splash-screen

I need a **full screen image on my splash screen** for IOS App build using react native. I have reffered different post but most of them explains spash screen with a logo at the center and none of them give a proper explanation of full screen splah image which fits all the device resolutions including iPad.

I have created a LaunchScreen.xib file with a View and Imageview as given below but it breaks in iPads, But it fits in iPhones to some extend (Though it has some black shade for high resolution iphones also)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="15400" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina5_5" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="15404"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleAspectFit" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="716"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="Default" id="IGQ-OV-TUd">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="-10" width="414" height="736"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMinX="YES" widthSizable="YES" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                </imageView>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.30980392156862746" green="0.42745098039215684" blue="0.47843137254901957" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
            <nil key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
            <modalPageSheetSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-20.289855072463769" y="107.60869565217392"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
    <resources>
        <image name="Default" width="682.66668701171875" height="910.66668701171875"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

I am attaching the settings screenshots of my View and ImageView below

[image]

[image]

I have created 3 dummy images for three different scales whose Content.json is given below

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "Dummy.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "Dummy@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "Dummy@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

All the above changes did'nt give a proper solution for my requirement. I am wondering if I need to create full screen images for all possible devices and include them in the Content.json file. But what width and height should I give in the settings(Scrrenshots)

Sombody please held me to provide the correct solution for my requirement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

You just need to set constraints to 0 from the top, left, right and bottom. This will automatically fit to all the devices.

**This is the code for my LaunchScreen.xib**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="15400" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="15404"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="376" height="480"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="Ios" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="mAG-fl-dgj">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="376.00000000000023" height="480"/>
                </imageView>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="mAG-fl-dgj" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="leading" id="4Qq-Mv-2hX"/>
                <constraint firstItem="mAG-fl-dgj" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="top" id="5G1-V8-uL4"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="mAG-fl-dgj" secondAttribute="trailing" id="61P-7a-W4I"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="mAG-fl-dgj" secondAttribute="bottom" id="b3b-rs-eay"/>
            </constraints>
            <nil key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="472.46376811594206" y="454.6875"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
    <resources>
        <image name="Ios" width="788" height="1400"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

> If you want to add a custom Splash Screen you can create manually in
>   your react application by creating a separate component.

Comment: Your suggestion works for me. Now the splash screen is loading as full screen. Only one issue left ie, My image get cropped off, How to prevent this. Do I need to create multple images for different screen and include them in Content.json?

Comment: :) Happy to help. Yes, you can add an image with 1x, 2x & 3x Or else you can try to change the content mode of the Image. It will show the preview on LauncScreen.xib itself. Let me know if you need any help. @Ajith

Comment: I have added App Icons & Launch Images > New Launch Image But Image not showing in LauncScreen.xib . ImageView Image selection dropdown, It lists only image assets with 1x, 2x & 3x .

Comment: Where exactly you have added Images?

Comment: I have solved the issue by adding screens in Contents.json , Thanks  :)

Comment: I've set the constraints to 0 after which the image does stretch but the boundary header and footer still remain white. How can I. make the image fill the top and bottom too?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this tool
[generator-rn-toolbox](https://github.com/bamlab/generator-rn-toolbox/blob/master/generators/assets/README.md)

Comment: Does it cut the image while resizing?

Answer (score 1):

need to set image height and width for IOS 3x

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
...
    <resources>
        <image name="SplashIcon" width="310.5" height="609"/>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

to

```
<image name="SplashIcon" width="1242" height="2436"/>
```